# counsel-ag shows no output

Tags: counsel, ag

I try to use `counsel-ag` to grep through all files in a directory for a string. Basically, I thought this is what it was made for. I have ag 2.2.0 installed via macports on OS X 10.10.5 and it works fine in shell mode.

If I am in the same directory an invoke `M-x counsel-ag` I get the ag prompt but if I type a string I get no matches but the message `No matches found`. I don't see any message or error. Is there any way to check what ag is doing and why `ivy` is not displaying the candidates like it does in other cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with `ivy-prescient`. Although, there is `ivy-prescient-excluded-commands` which contains `counsel-ag` to prevent the regex generation from being disturbed I have to add

```
(setq ivy-re-builders-alist
        '((swiper . ivy--regex-plus)
          (counsel-ag . ivy--regex-plus)
          (counsel-rg . ivy--regex-plus)
          (t      . ivy-prescient-re-builder)))
```

to get `counsel-ag` working again.